# What is the difference between the onSeccess and select options of useQuery in tanstack query?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-query

When I use useQuery, it deduces the data from the return value of queryFn, but when I use the select option, it does not deduce the converted type of select, and it deduces the type of the return value of queryFn, but the type I want to use in the end is the converted type from select, so I wonder if I should convert the data through select and add the type explicitly again.

Comment: Please, provide the code sample.

Comment: you're probably messing up the type inference by providing generics manually. see: https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/react/typescript#type-inference and https://tkdodo.eu/blog/react-query-and-type-script#type-inference